# Entity Framework: How to detect external changes to database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that changes lots of data in the database. This stored procedure is called from the application that at the same time uses EF for data operations.

So I click a button, stored procedure is run at the database, data is changed and EF shows old data to the user.

Is there a way to force the DbContext or ObjectContext to refresh data from database? ObjectContext.Refresh() may be the solution but I do not want to call this method for every single table that may be changed. I want all the tables to be refreshed in one move.

I am using Entity Framework 5, targeting .NET 4.0

**EDIT: Added data is available but modification on existing data is not reflected by EF. I see the newly added records but I cannot see the changes I made to existing records.**

Comment: I'm afraid, you cannot do this. And, maybe this is good, because in other case on this global context refresh whole your database will be selected to your application.

Comment: I'm wondering because DBContext take always data from Database directly also if you have cashed. You have to refesh your data and not the dataContext I mean reload the data from DB?

Comment: @BassamAlugili, I've clarified the problem, please take a look at the edit.

Comment: With SignalR this is definitly possible. Check out this blog post from  Brij: http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency

Comment: @Serv, That looks a good tool but I don't have problem with being notified about changes. I can't force EF to load updated data from database. It won't update properties of entities that have changed.

Comment: In the mentioned blog article, the user changes data and the updated data gets instantly pushed to all clients. Isn't this what you want?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `DbContext` should be short-lived. Create it, run your query, and dispose it.

```
using (var context = new MyProject.DbContext())
{
    // run your query here
}
```

Don't keep your context around. That way you won't have any issues with old data.

Comment: I am using the same context for repositories and the context is registered by IoC.

Comment: @Mert With an IoC library you can still have a short-lived context. For example, using Autofac and Web API you can do `builder.Register(c => context).As<IIntranetContext>().InstancePerApiRequest();`

Comment: The problem is that I would need to reinitialize all the repo's because they depend on the context. Service layer interacts with repo's not context.

Comment: @Mert Well how do your repositories access the context? Set them up so they get a fresh context instance for every request.

Comment: @Stihn, Thank you, I will try that if I cannot find a better solution.

Comment: I found no easy way to refresh the data context to reflect external changes, also it is a good practice to have short-lived contexts.

Comment: then what's the point of using EF if you have to work always with detached entities? When you need by chance `oCustomer.Orders` do you have to re-attach it to a new context to retrieve its Orders?

Comment: @IvanFerrerVilla Sorry for not responding earlier, I must have missed the notification. Usually you'll map the entities immediately after retrieving them, to business objects or view models (or something else). To update, you either retrieve the entity again and modify the properties (easier), or you manually attach an entity with just the Primary Key field(s) set, fill in the properties and mark them as having changed (no `select` query executed). I haven't actively used EF for a few years now, so I'm not up to speed with regards to today's best practices.

Comment: @IvanFerrerVilla See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17442858/247702 for an example of the manual attach method.

Comment: thanks @Stijn. I use to create a single tabbed form to edit for instance all data related to one customer: contacts, addresses, documents, etc. I love using entities because of that child lazy loading functionality: it loads childs only when needed. But working detached, lazy loading becomes useless. I think I'll need to rethink how I edit those childs. Regards

Answer (score 3):

```
db = new DbContext())
var context= ((Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
context.Refresh(Core.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Unchanged | EntityState.Modified))
```