# What happens to my DbContext after I run a stored procedure that modifies my entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, dbcontext, entity-framework-6

**Scenario**: 
I have a custom `DbContext`. I am using the `StoreConnection` property of the underlying `ObjectContext` to run a stored procedure that modifies several entities (which have a `DbSet` in my custom `DbContext`). My DbContext and Repositories are supplied by Unity v3.

**Example**:

```
private MyContext _ctx;
private IGenericRepository<Foo>();
private IGenericRepository<Bar>();

public void DoSomethingFooAndBar()
{
    var connection = _ctx.StoreConnection; //Exposed ObjectContext.StoreConnection in my custom context
    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "dbo.ModifyFooAndBar";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    //What is the state of my DbSet<Foo> and DbSet<Bar>?
}
```

**Question**: 
Do I run the risk of having a stale `DbContext` after this stored procedure and, if so, how do I get it to become current short of disposing of it and creating a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DbContext will be stale at this point, if you continue to use it after running the stored proc. According to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18830466/3294324) you may be able to update your context without creating a new one.

You could try something like this:

```
var Context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_ctx).ObjectContext;
Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries());
```